# Is the an efficient way to generate missing rows in sparse data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL table that has rows representing 10 minutes bars:

```
CREATE TABLE "P_Data"
(
  "Date" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  "Value" double precision,

)
```

The data is sparse:

```
00:10:00,  73
00:20:00,  74
00:40:00,  71
```

I would like to be able to generate the missing rows taking the last value:

```
00:10:00,  73
00:20:00,  74
00:30:00,  74
00:40:00,  71
```

How can I achieve this - can it be done with a "VIEW"?

Comment: `00:10:00` is not what a timestamp looks like... what is your actual data?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a recursive CTE.

Lets say your table is called P_Data, such a query would look like this:

```
-- first get the min and max for the range
WITH minmax as
(
   SELECT min(Date) as min_date, max(Date) as max_date
   FROM P_Data
), base_list  as -- now build a list of all our timestamps, recursively
(
   SELECT min_date as date_item
   FROM minmax

   UNION ALL

   SELECT date_item + 10 minutes as date_item
   FROM base_list, minmax
   WHERE date_item + 10 minutes < date_max 
)
-- now join this to our data
SELECT date_item, Value
FROM base_list
LEFT JOIN P_Data on base_list.date_item = P_Data.Date
```

You can also do this with a view if you have a table with a single counting column that has more rows than you have in your final result. But I'll leave that implementation up to you -- or you can ask in a comment if you need it.